# Angular momentum in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

My doubt is about the spin of particles. I am unable to imagine spin as a physical quantity.
So what is spin actually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/)

Comment: my answer  here may help      https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/586741/is-spin-necessary-for-electromagnetism/586743#586743